# Is it possible to forbid MySQL row modifications?

Tags: mysql, row

I have a MySQL table storing some data that I do not want to be modified by anyone. Meaning that even the DB administrator should not be allowed to modify it. Is there any way I could possibly forbid the modification of table rows from everyone including the DB admin?

I've researched that this could partially be achieved by read/write locks. However, the DB admin would still be allowed to log in with the username that holds the lock and take advantage of it.

My goal is to forbid modification on table records to everyone including DB admin. Is there any way I could achieve this with MySQL?

Comment: The admin can always do what they want even if you forbid them to do something, they can alter the system to allow it to them. But you don't need to give the password for administrative accounts to anyone. To restrict access on a table or tables lookup `REVOKE`.

Comment: Locks have nothing to do with permissions. They just block access temporarily while another process is working with the table or row, to ensure consistency across multiple queries.

Comment: @stickybit is right. Safe that case, you could add an extra flag column, that is set to false during insert, and add a trigger that switches it to true during any update.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can restrict access on tables with REVOKE. The reason why I want to restrict access to a specific table for everyone is that I am creating an auction application. The idea is that I want to restrict access to the bid table to everyone so a potential malicious auctioneer (DB admin) would not be allowed to manipulate the outcome of the auction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, it will be difficult to restrict things to an admin as it can do almost everything.

You can create a trigger that prevents updates. I have 2 solutions with 2 different triggers

**Example 1**

This version does not send error, but is sensible to schema modifications. It also affects "0 line"

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE not_updatable(
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  data varchar(50)
);

-- Trigger
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER not_updatable_after_update
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON not_updatable
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.id=OLD.id, NEW.data=OLD.data;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Results :

```
mariadb@localhost:test> CREATE TABLE not_updatable(
                          id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
                          data varchar(50)
                        );
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Time: 0.236s
mariadb@localhost:test> CREATE TRIGGER not_updatable_after_update
                    ->    BEFORE UPDATE
                    ->    ON not_updatable
                    ->    FOR EACH ROW
                    ->    BEGIN
                    ->      SET NEW.id=OLD.id, NEW.data=OLD.data;
                    ->    END;
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Time: 0.070s
mariadb@localhost:test> insert into not_updatable(data) values ('test 1'), ('test 2');
Query OK, 2 rows affected
Time: 0.043s
mariadb@localhost:test> select * from not_updatable;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
|------+--------|
| 1    | test 1 |
| 2    | test 2 |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set
Time: 0.004s
mariadb@localhost:test> update not_updatable set data = 'test 3' where id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Time: 0.001s
mariadb@localhost:test> select * from not_updatable;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
|------+--------|
| 1    | test 1 |
| 2    | test 2 |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set
Time: 0.003s
```

**Example 2**

This, raises an error, and thus, is more visible to an attacker

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE not_updatable(
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  data varchar(50)
);

-- Trigger
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER not_updatable_after_update
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON not_updatable
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Don''t try to cheat !';
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Results :

```
mariadb srumeu@localhost:test> drop trigger not_updatable_after_update;
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Time: 0.000s
mariadb srumeu@localhost:test> CREATE TRIGGER not_updatable_after_update
                            ->   BEFORE UPDATE
                            ->   ON not_updatable
                            ->   FOR EACH ROW
                            ->   BEGIN
                            ->     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Don''t try to cheat !';
                            ->   END;
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Time: 0.078s
mariadb srumeu@localhost:test> update not_updatable set data = 'test 3' where id = 1;
(1644, "Don't try to cheat !")
mariadb srumeu@localhost:test> select * from not_updatable;
+------+--------+
| id   | data   |
|------+--------|
| 1    | test 1 |
| 2    | test 2 |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set
Time: 0.014s
```

Answer (score 0):

The admin account always has full control over the databases on the server. Even if you `revoke` permissions to a table, the admin can `grant` themselves permissions. From a common-sense point of view, this makes sense; what would you do if you did want to update a row in that table? Nuke the whole server and re-insert?

The best you can do is setup some auditing. If you can take backups of the table, and periodically compare the table to the backups, that's one potential method. Be sure to store the backup in a location that your administrator cannot access.  Of course, there are all sorts of other potential problems, so that's hardly ideal.

If you are willing to switch to MariaDB, you could take advantage of the [System-Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/). I wouldn't normally suggest "try a different RDBMS", but MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, so that transition might not be as painful as switching to, say Oracle.

Comment: The reason why I want to restrict access to a specific table for everyone is that I am creating an auction application. The idea is that I want to restrict access to the bid table to everyone so a potential malicious auctioneer (DB admin) would not be allowed to manipulate the outcome of the auction.

Comment: @Ne7WoRK if the user (the auctioneer) is also the admin, then the only options are to either trust everything that the user does, or trust none of it. Your best bet would be to provide bidders with a receipt of their bid. So if the auctioneer fraudulently "sells" an item to someone with a lower bid than what a legitimate bidder bid, then that bidder would have a receipt to prove that they bid higher. The same idea prevents the auctioneer from fraudulently claiming that a bidder placed a higher bid than they really did.

Comment: consider a situation where a malicious auctioneer Bob and malicious bidder Alice. Alice contacts Bob and tells him - "Hey I would really like to win this item can you help me I will pay you." This means that the manipulation of the bid can be arranged between the two malicious entities (Alice and Bob) without the knowledge of the other participants. Each user will have his receipt, but then how would they know auctioneer and winner haven't set up the auction outcome?

Comment: @Ne7WoRK What could Bob and Alice actually conspire to do though? If Alice bids 10 gold coins, and then Charlie comes along and bids 20 gold coins, but Alice still won, the fraud would be obvious to Charlie with his receipt. If the auctioneer upped Alice's bid to 30 gold coins in the DB, then it would not match Alice's receipt - not to mention that the seller will now expect to receive 30 gold coins, so Alice may as well have bid high anyway. Perhaps you could have a scenario where the auctioneer waits for the auction to end, then inserts Alice's higher bid, but then there'd be no receipt.

Comment: I should clarify too: "receipt" is just a concept for an auditing trail. It doesn't have to literally be sending an email to the bidder. Another method of auditing the data could be creating a hash of the bid amount with a salt that is not accessible to the auctioneer (if your auctioneer has access to both your database and your source code, then your system is fully compromised...), and then both the hash and the bid amount is stored in your table. Then when you validate the auction at the end, you hash the bid amount with the same salt, and verify that they match.

Comment: ...Basically what I'm saying is that you can't rely on keeping your data from being modified - instead, you need to be able to audit and/or validate the integrity of the data. The way that you do that will rely heavily on how your system is designed, as well as how much privilege (to modify data) and knowledge (of how your auditing/security is performed) you provide to the auctioneer.